# Why does my updated php now show with php -v command?

Tags: php, macos, system

I just ran an update on my php to 5.4.

I closed my terminal to refresh and ran php -v and it gives me the older version still?

Does anyone know why this would happen? Do I need to restart my machine?

I am a bit stumbled on this one!

Thanks

Comment: Check if command `which php` shows you php binary you expect. It seems that you have 2 different versions installed.

Comment: that gives me /usr/bin/PHP which is what I updated before this.

Comment: It just means that your update process either did not update anything, or updated something other than `/usr/bin/php`